# Json code not working correctly

Tags: javascript, json

Error:

[image]

I am trying to delete the record of message but there is an error and it won't be delete the record. What the error in this code please tell me.

MessageView:

```
<ul>
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($messages as $message)
            <li class="list-group-item"> {{$message->user->name}} : {{$message->message}}
                @if($message->user_id === Auth::user()->id){
                    <a data-id="{{$message->id}}" class="delete-message">Delete</a> /
                    <a href="/message/edit/{{$message->id}}">Edit </a>
                }@endif
            </li>
    </ul>
```

JSON:

```
$(".delete-message").on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
    _this = $(this);
console.log(id);

var _confirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this message?");

if(_confirm){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'DELETE',
        url : '/delete/message/',
        data : {
            id : id,
            _token : $("meta[name=token]").attr('content')
        },
        success : function(res){
            if(res.deleted){
                $(_this).parents('list-group-item').slideUp(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        }
    });
}else{
    console.log("Never mind!");
}
```

});

Comment: Look at the developer console to see the error..or try debugging.

Comment: Please post your server-side method.

Comment: Error 500, as the error message states is an Internal Server error; it is a problem with the server-side code, not the JS. That said, the error could be caused by your JS sending it bad parameters that are causing the error. Look at the error logs on your server to see what error messages are being generated on the server; that might tell you what it wrong with the back-end script.